# How to make canvas rectangule move with ease stops up and down?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to achieve lifter effect on canvas rectangule with ease move, stop, move (like stops in every floor) from the top floor moves down the same. Tried a lot by google, can not figure out. Animation should start on windows load.

```js
var stage = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = stage.getContext('2d'),
  x = 235,
  y = 450,
  wid = 30,
  hei = 50;

function drawRect(x, y, wid, hei) {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#666';
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, wid, hei);
}

drawRect(x, y, wid, hei);

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var keyPr = event.keyCode; //Key code of key pressed

  if (keyPr === 38 && y > 100) {
    y = y - 100; //top arrow subtract 100 from current
  } else if (keyPr === 40 && y <= 400) {
    y = y + 100; //bottom arrow add 100 from current
  }

  /* comment this below do draw path */
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  drawRect(x, y, wid, hei);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code is moving the rectangle fine ... can you explain what exactly is wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in your question what kind of movement you want to see ...

Here is one example of smaller increments that way we move to a destination, instead of a "jump" to the final destination, hopefully that gets you closer to what you need.

```js
var stage = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = stage.getContext('2d');
var rect = { x: 50, y: 150, w: 15, h: 25, to: {x: 50, y: 150}};

function drawRect(rect) {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#666';
  ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
  if (rect.y != rect.to.y) {
    rect.y += (rect.y > rect.to.y)? -1: 1
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  drawRect(rect);
}

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 38 && rect.to.y > 20) {
    rect.to.y -= 30; //top arrow subtract 100 from current
  } else if (event.keyCode === 40 && rect.to.y <= 140) {
    rect.to.y += 30; //bottom arrow add 100 from current
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 25)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Key elements I introduced:

- `setInterval(draw, 25)` that will loop every 25 miliseconds and draw everything
- `var rect = { x: 50, y: 150, w: 15, h: 25, to: {x: 50, y: 150}};` an object to keep all rectangle attributes together the `to` is our destination
- `if (rect.y != rect.to.y) {` that is a condition to check if current position is different than the destination, and if it is we move 1 pixel towards destination